# Problems with Pthreads; Changing value, etc

Tags: c, pthreads

I know the title's vague, I just couldn't figure out what else to call it.

sleeper.h

```
#ifndef SLEEPER_H
#define SLEEPER_H
#include <unistd.h>

int rideTime(int, int);
void walkAroundTime(int);

#endif
```

sleeper.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "sleeper.h"

int rideTime(int id, int car) {

int seconds = ( rand() % 5) + 1 ;
printf ("Person %d is riding car %d for  %d seconds.\n", id, car, seconds);
sleep (seconds); 

return car;

}

void walkAroundTime(int id) {

int seconds = (rand() % 10) + 1 ;
printf ("Person %d is walking around for  %d seconds.\n", id, seconds);
sleep (seconds);

}
```

bumper_cars.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "sleeper.h"

void* person(void*);
int getInLine(int);
void returnCar(int);

pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t car_availability = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
int available_cars;
int num_cars;
int* cars;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   num_cars = atoi(argv[1]);
   int num_people = atoi(argv[2]);
   int sim_time = atoi(argv[3]);

   available_cars = num_cars;
   cars = calloc(num_cars, sizeof(int));
   pthread_t* threads = calloc(num_people, sizeof(pthread_t));

    srand((unsigned)time (NULL));

   for (int i = 0; i < num_cars; i++) {
      cars[i] = 1;
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < num_people; i++) {
        int* id = malloc(sizeof(*id));
      *id = i + 1;
      pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, person, (void*)(id));
   }

    //printf("MAIN: Sleeping for %d seconds\n", sim_time);
   sleep(sim_time);
    //printf("Done sleeping.\n");

   for (int i = 0; i < num_people; i++) {
      pthread_cancel(threads[i]);
   }

   printf("Simulation complete.\n");

   pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);
   free(cars);
   free(threads);

   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void* person(void* arg) {
    int car = 0;
   int id = *((int *) arg);
   while (1) {
      walkAroundTime(id);
      car = getInLine(id);
      rideTime(id, car);
      returnCar(car);
   }
}

int getInLine(int id) {
    int car = 0;

    printf("Person %d is waiting for a car.\n", id);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);

    if (available_cars == 0) {
        pthread_cond_wait(&car_availability,&lock);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num_cars; i++) {
        if (cars[i] == 1) {
            car = i + 1;
            cars[i] = 0;
            break;
        }
    } 
    available_cars--;

    return car;
}

void returnCar(int carID) {
    available_cars++;
    cars[carID] = 1;
    printf("Car %d has been returned.\n", carID);
   pthread_cond_broadcast(&car_availability);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}
```

So... I have two problems with my program. The most significant is that it only works for 1 car. If there are multiple cars and one is taken all the other people still must wait for it to be returned.

The second, less significant problem is that when I start the code with only 1 car, the id of the car starts at 0, then alternates between 1 and 0, when it should just be 1. Looking at my code, it's not obvious to me where these problems are originating... and gdb is proving to be rather unhelpful.

Comment: in sleeper.h, why is the unistd.h file being included?  the two prototypes in the file do not use any of the items defined in unistd.h.   In general, includes in header files are only for types being used later in the header file.  If any of the contents of unistd.h are needed in some source file, then that source file is where the include should be located

Comment: You aren't checking whether *any* of your pthreads functions succeed. You have no moral right to expect your program to work if you deliberately fail to check for errors.

Comment: the parameter 'argc' is not used, so the compiler will raise a warning.  I.E. this code does not cleanly compile.  also the code assumes the correct parameters (and number of parameters) were entered on the command line.  a check of argc should be performed, before getting any of the parameters, to assure the command line is correct. then after each call to atoi() should check the converted value to assure it is usable/valid

Comment: the returned values from malloc and calloc should always be checked (!= NULL) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: Yeah I know, the error checking is sloppy. It's just a homework assignment and there isn't going to be error-checking for the grading so I'm being lazy with it.

Comment: Shouldn't you initialize your locks:
pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL);

Same comment for pthread_cond_init(...)

Comment: When getInLine is executed, the current car entry is set to 0  that is pprobably what you are seeing when the car value shifts between 0 and 1

Comment: @jaybers: No, the call to `pthread_mutex_init()` is not necessary because the mutex has been statically initialised with `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIAZER` (and the same for the condition variable).

Comment: "It's just a homework assignment and there isn't going to be error-checking for the grading so I'm being lazy with it" - well, now you've learned the error of your ways. Error checking isn't just for getting grades - it's for figuring out why your program isn't working. If you can't be bothered to check for errors yourself, why do you expect people on Stack Overflow to do it for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are holding the lock for too long once you acquire it to get the car.  I modified your function in this way, with changes noted in comments:

```
int getInLine(int id) {
    int car = 0;

    printf("Person %d is waiting for a car.\n", id);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);

    // Use a while loop because pthread_cond_wait() is subject to
    // spurious awakenings.
    while (available_cars == 0) {
        pthread_cond_wait(&car_availability,&lock);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num_cars; i++) {
        if (cars[i] == 1) {
            car = i + 1;
            cars[i] = 0;
            break;
        }
    } 
    available_cars--;
    // Unlock the mutex here now that we are done acquiring the car.
    // If we don't unlock the mutex here, no one else can acquire a car.
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

    return car;
}

void returnCar(int carID) {
    // Lock the mutex here before returning the car.
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    available_cars++;
    // Need -1 here because carID is one bigger than the index.
    cars[carID-1] = 1;
    printf("Car %d has been returned.\n", carID);
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&car_availability);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}
```

By the way, I noticed that you use `rand()` to generate random numbers.  However, if multiple threads call `rand()` at the same time you will get the same random number (at least that's what happened when I ran your program).  You should use `rand_r()` instead and create different seeds for each thread.

Comment: The `while()` loop is necessary here even without spurious wakeups - if multiple people are waiting for a car, they'll *all* be woken up when a car is returned, but only one of them will actually see `available_cars` greater than zero - the rest have to go back to sleep.

Comment: @caf Good point.  I was thinking that he was using `pthread_cond_signal` but I see that there is a broadcast instead.

Comment: Thank you! I think this works, but I'm not 100% sure since the numbers are still wonky...

Comment: @Rui: If you ever see a person get in car zero, then that means that the `for()` loop in `getInLine()` didn't find an available car.  In turn this means either that the `availableCars` variable got out of synch with the car array, or you didn't use the `while()` loop around `pthread_cond_wait()` like this answer suggests.

Comment: @Rui See my edit.  You were adding one to the car index when you got the car, but not subtracting one from the index when you returned the car.